# MySQL select the minimum value from the maximum values

Tags: mysql

I want to select the minimum of the max values returned from all the tables. Here's my sql command for searching all the max values:

```
SELECT MAX(value) FROM temperatureTable 
UNION 
SELECT MAX(value) FROM resistanceTable 
UNION 
SELECT MAX(value) FROM pressureTable;
```

Here's the result:

```
    {
        "MAX(value)": "8.113130E-1"
    },
    {
        "MAX(value)": "6.445700E+0"
    },
    {
        "MAX(value)": "6.526210E-8"
    }
```

How do I select the minimum value `6.445700E+0` with sql command?

Also, how do I access the MAX(value)/MIN(value) from the return Rawdatapackage?

```
result[0].Max(value) // will generate an error because of the '()'.
```

Comment: why don't you sort the resultset and pick the minimum value?

Comment: store the result in a tmp table and select the min value from this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subquery technique:

```
SELECT MIN(tmp.value) 
FROM  
(   SELECT MAX(value) AS value 
    FROM temperatureTable 
UNION    
    SELECT MAX(value) AS value 
    FROM resistanceTable
UNION
    SELECT MAX(value) AS value 
    FROM pressureTable
) AS tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT MAX(value) as maxValue FROM temperatureTable 
UNION 
SELECT MAX(value) FROM resistanceTable 
UNION 
SELECT MAX(value) FROM pressureTable;
```

and access results like:

```
result[0].maxValue  
// using "as someAlias" names that field result "someAlias"
```

If you want the minimum max value, you can:

```
Select min(maxValue) as minValue FROM (
    SELECT MAX(value) as maxValue FROM temperatureTable 
    UNION 
    SELECT MAX(value) FROM resistanceTable 
    UNION 
    SELECT MAX(value) FROM pressureTable;
) x
```

I'm not sure it makes any sense to do *this*, since those tables hold *different* types of measurements.

Comment: Is the 'x' a typo at the end?

Comment: no, it's the alias of the joint selects. Using `SELECT  something FROM (subselects)` needs an alias